# (Ubuntu Server 20.04) I was able to share a hard drive through samba, but I can't get it to work with my other hard drive. I'm moving in circles

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, samba, nas

I recently got a home server (HPE Gen 10) - I loaded ubuntu server on it, hoping to run some virtual machines but i got over my head trying to install KVM.

I decided to just try Samba to share a drive between this ubuntu server, my Win10 desktop, a chromeOS laptop and my wife's Win10 tablet.  After hours of modifying the .conf file, I got it to work, but it appears to be working on the main hard drive (SDD).

I have a 1 TB hard drive and 2 4TB hard drives on the server (SDA, SDB, SDC), all with /dev/sdX as the path. Ubuntu automatically mounted the drives, and there's nothing on the drives i NEED to keep.  All i want is to use the 1TB drive as NAS storage, since that should be simple enough Lol

WhenI change the path to /dev/sdX, it won't use that hard drive for the share.  When i modify conf to change the path to /Share, it will work, but it's the same hard drive i got originally.

I attempt to mount the hard drive I want (SDA1) with the /Share folder, but I get

> mount: /Share: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I did partitian the whole drive using NTFS, but this headache is getting beyond me.  It should be as simple as changing the path, but maybe I've been modifying so much that the /Share folder is linking to two hard drives (everytime I reboot the server, the ddrive letter changes)

This is my conf setup

> [Share]
>           comment = Family Share
>           path = /Share
>           browsable = yes
>           guest ok = yes
>           read only = no
>           create mask = 0755
>           directory mask = 0700
>           valid users = User1, User2, User1PC

I'm new to this - i just got my net+ last month!  All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too big for one answer since it involves Samba and partition mounting. All I can do is offer a template on how to mount an ntfs partition in Linux and maybe the samba part will take care of itself.

[1] Run the following command to determine the correct **UUID** number for your partition:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

Note: You mentioned that Ubuntu automatically mounted these secondary partitions. The only thing Ubuntu automatically mounts is the partition the OS resides in so if the partition is mounted ( and the command above will tell you that ) unmount it. Then check to see if you already have an entry in **/etc/fstab** for the ntfs partition and comment out the line by placing a # sign at the beginning of the line.

[2] Create the mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /Share
```

[3] Edit /etc/fstab and at the bottom of the file instruct the system to mount the partition at boot - replace the UUID number below with the one you found in step [1]:

```
UUID=200C11850C1156DE /Share ntfs defaults,nofail 0 0
```

[4] Run this command to mount it now:

```
sudo mount -a
```

[5] Verify the contents of the mounted partition.